# How to make JavaScript execute keyboard combinations

Tags: javascript, keyboard, electron

I was wondering if there is a way to make JavaScript execute keyboard combinations.

I am making an application in Electron and I can't get my custom Minimize and Maximize buttons to work on Windows. I tried running the application on Mac and it works perfectly. So I was thinking about just making a button that can execute keyboard commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be alt+space+n to minimize but secure reasons I guess it won't work.

```
$("#minimize").click(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    //e.which = 115;       // # F4 code value
    e.altKey = true;     // Alt key pressed
    e.which = 32;      //space key
    //e.which = 78;      //n key
    $("#minimize").trigger(e);

});
```